# Determine if finished printing using Java

Tags: java, printing

Does anyone know how can I determine if a physical printer finished printing using java? I already tried the Job Listener, Job Watcher, and Job Events but all of these did not work.

Here is the code I used:

```
private static class PDFPrintJobListener implements PrintJobListener {

    private static final boolean showMessages=false;

    @Override
    public void printDataTransferCompleted(final PrintJobEvent printJobEvent) {
        if(showMessages) {
            System.out.println("printDataTransferCompleted=" + printJobEvent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void printJobCompleted(final PrintJobEvent printJobEvent) {
        if(showMessages) {
            System.out.println("printJobCompleted=" + printJobEvent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void printJobFailed(final PrintJobEvent printJobEvent) {
        if(showMessages) {
            System.out.println("printJobEvent=" + printJobEvent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void printJobCanceled(final PrintJobEvent printJobEvent) {
        if(showMessages) {
            System.out.println("printJobFailed=" + printJobEvent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void printJobNoMoreEvents(final PrintJobEvent printJobEvent) {
        if(showMessages) {
            System.out.println("printJobNoMoreEvents=" + printJobEvent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void printJobRequiresAttention(final PrintJobEvent printJobEvent) {
        if(showMessages) {
            System.out.println("printJobRequiresAttention=" + printJobEvent);
        }
    }
```

I tried to use listeners but no output is received whether the printer finished printing or the printer failed to print the document. I also searched other people's question related to this but nobody knows the answer. There are times when Data Transfer Completed is the only output in the listener. So I want to know how to determine if a printer finished printing a document. Thanks

Comment: There is normally no direct connection between your program and the printer.  All modern operating systems "spool" the print data, storing it temporarily on disk before sending the stream to the physical printer.  You might be able to query the printer status using a different operating system API, but that would be a separate operation unrelated to the creation of the print job, and you might not know when your specific job completed if there were many jobs queued ahead of yours in the print queue.

Answer (score 0):

First few link of google search fetches [this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/print/determine-that-print-job-has-finished/). Here all the methods provided by `PrintJobAdapter` are overridden to have the following method call in their implementation:

```
private void signalCompletion() {

synchronized (JobCompleteMonitor.this) {

    completed = true;

    JobCompleteMonitor.this.notify();

}
```

This should be self explanatory that `notify()` wakes up the first thread that called `wait()` on the same object in the main method.